# Why is this calculation of $ \lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin ^{2} x}-\frac{\cos ^{2} x}{x^{2}}\right) $ wrong?

Tags: limits

$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin ^{2} x}-\frac{\cos ^{2} x}{x^{2}}\right)
$$
$$
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{x^2-\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}{x^2\sin^2x}\right)
$$
$$
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x} - \cos^2x}{x^2} \right)
$$
$$
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{1-\cos^2x}{x^2} \right)=1
$$
But the correct answer is 4/3.

P.S. Can someone give an overall principle when we can substitute an expression and when not?

Comment: You seem to have replaced $x^2/\sin^2(x)$ with $1$

Comment: @Integrand But $$ \lim_{x->0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$ is that right?

Comment: Not clear how you get $1/2.$ $1-\cos^2 x=\sin^2x,$ so your last limit should be $1.$ It is true that $$\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\to \frac12,$$ but not if $1-\cos^2x$ is in the numerator. not sure why $1$ differs from $4/3,$ however.

Comment: @mingzixingshi See [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/888233) to learn formatting mathematical expressions and equations.

Comment: @soupless OP seams to have formatted the post fine. Comments are a little harder to get right, with no feedback.

Comment: Oh that's my mistake@ThomasAndrews

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Op did a mistake before the last step too. He seems to be having problem with algebra of limits.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha What is the mistake before the last line?

Comment: @mingzixingshi true, but that doesn't mean you can substitute it here. For example, if we have $\lim_{x\to 0}(1-\sin(x)/x )/x^2$, using your substitution we have $0$ while the actual limit is $1/6$.

Comment: @Integrand We can only substitute when it is a factor of the whole formula , am I right?

Comment: OP is claiming you can evaluate a 'sublimit' first, which you cannot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the third line to the fourth you replaced $\frac {x^2}{\sin^2 x}$ with $1$.  The $1$s will cancel, so we are interested in the next order term.  You should replace it with $\frac {x^2}{\sin^2 x} = 1+\frac {x^2}3+O(x^4)$.  That gives the missing $\frac 13$

Answer (score 2):

In general, $$\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) \ne \lim_{x \to a} f\left(\lim_{x \to a} g(x)\right).$$
In other words, taking a limit of an expression inside a function simply because it exists, does not mean that the overall limit of that function will still behave the same way.

For a simpler counterexample, we could use your same flawed reasoning to argue
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1 + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \right)^x = \lim_{x \to \infty} (1 + 0)^x = \lim_{x \to \infty} 1^x = 1.$$  This is obviously wrong; moreover, it gives some insight as to *why* it is wrong:  the expressions $1/x$ and $x$ are related to each other as $x \to \infty$; they cannot be evaluated independently of each other.

---

What would be a correct evaluation of your limit?  Those who enjoy working with power series would immediately proceed to write
$$\frac{1}{\sin^2 x} = \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{x^2}{15} + O(x^4),$$
$$\frac{\cos^2 x}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} - 1 + \frac{x^2}{3} + O(x^4),$$
which gives us $$\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2 x} - \frac{\cos^2 x}{x^2}\right) = \frac{4}{3} - \frac{4x^2}{15} + O(x^4),$$ so our limit is $\frac{4}{3}$ (note it is unnecessary to expand out to the second order).

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer:** Following heropup's remark:

**Your mistake:**
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \frac{\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x} - \cos^2x}{x^2} \right)$$

If in this step, you're replacing $\frac{x^{2}}{\sin^{2}x}$ with $1$, you will also have to replace $\cos^{2}x$ with $1$ and the denominator by $0$.

**Concept:**

You cannot apply sub-limits only for parts of the expression. Either apply on all the terms of the expression or none.